# Meaning of "reckless with misery"

Tags: phrase-meaning

I have came across this phrase twice.Once in Oliver Twist and now again in "[My financial Career](https://web.iiit.ac.in/~nirnimesh/Literature/MyFinancialCareer.htm)" by Stephen Leacock.

> **Reckless with misery**, I made up my mind. 'Yes the whole thing.' 'You withdraw your money from the bank?' 'Every cent of it.' 'Are you not going to deposit any more?' said the clerk, astonished. 'Never.' A foolish hope struck me that they might think something had insulted me while I was writing the cheque and that I had ...

Answer (score 0):

It is a literary use of the preposition ***[with](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/with)*** that here means:

> (of cause) owing to:
>
> - *to die with pneumonia; to pale with fear.*

He was reckless because of misery.

(Dictionary.com)

Comment: In other words, he was so miserable that he didn't care what happened to him.

Comment: @KateBunting is correct.

Comment: Abdul, which phrase, in specific words, did you come across twice, please?

Do you recognise that nothing after *Reckless with misery, I made up my mind* matters? Beneath that, would you mind asking a Question?

Since you didn’t, may we assume you intended to ask what someone else meant by *Reckless with misery, I made up my mind*?

I made up my mind, has nothing to do with Reckless with misery in ordinary language. In your poem it might mean everything.

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin - why do think my answer is not correct. What does it mean in your opinion?

Comment: Sorry, 159691; I've now no idea